# How to implement console commands while server is running in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm making a game server and I would like to type commands after I run the server from SSH.
For example: addbot, generatemap, kickplayer, etc.

Like in Half-life or any other gameserver. How can I make Node.js listen to my commands and still keep the server running in SSH?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use **process.stdin** like this:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
  console.log(text);
  if (text.trim() === 'quit') {
    done();
  }
});

function done() {
  console.log('Now that process.stdin is paused, there is nothing more to do.');
  process.exit();
}
```

Otherwise, you can use helper libraries like prompt https://github.com/flatiron/prompt which lets you do this:

```
var prompt = require('prompt');

// Start the prompt
prompt.start();

// Get two properties from the user: username and email
prompt.get(['username', 'email'], function (err, result) {

  // Log the results.
  console.log('Command-line input received:');
  console.log('  username: ' + result.username);
  console.log('  email: ' + result.email);
})
```

Comment: "quit" command doesn't work :P It seems like "text" variable has this text + "enter" ;) How to delete this enter?

Comment: @Ludwik11 use .trim()

Comment: Wow, great, and when you combine with eval() you can execute directly JS. so cool! Thanks!